# Compactness of closed unit ball $\bar B(0,1)$ in normed space

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be normed space.

How does compactness of any closed ball $\bar B(a,r)\; a \in X, r >0 \,$ relate to compactness of unit closed ball in $X$ ?

I have to prove in homework assignment that $\bar B(a,r)$ is compact iff $\bar B(0,1)$ is compact.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By looking at the homeomorphism $x\rightarrow\dfrac{x-a}{r}$.

Comment: Is premise for this  

$x \rightarrow d(x,a) \leq r$ ?

Comment: Yes, starting from $r$-ball.